# How to create a bxslider with wordpress post type categories

Tags: wordpress, bxslider

I have a taxonomy called portfolio_cat with its categories.So now i need to create a slider with that categories as a title and their post items.How i can do that? What Wordpress loop i need to have so i could put in a slider Wordpress categories with their posts?

I dont know how to customize this loop to fit in

```
<?php
       $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 7, 'order' => ASC ) );
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
$portfolioArgs = array(
'order' => 'ASC',
'post_type' => 'portfolio', 
'posts_per_page' => 7,
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_cat',
        'field' => 'slug'
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $portfolioArgs );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();  ?>
<div class="slide">
    <?php the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' ); ?>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
<?php
  endwhile; 
?>
```

Comment: The question is to slide custom post type categories this loop will slide all post items of this post type @Nimmi

Comment: It is displaying all posts not the category and its posts @Nimmi

Comment: In some way i need to display a category and its posts underneath the category name.is that possible?

Comment: if you can please show image how it is right now and how you want it to display would be more helpful.